# Dell Stylus 750-AAHC not working on Dell Inspiron 17 7000 series

Tags: dell, touchscreen, elantech, stylus

on my Dell Inspiron 17 7778 (2-in-1) notebook the Dell Stylus 750-AAHC  does not work in a correct way. When I touch the screen with the pen the behavior is completely random. It is impossible to use the pen on the screen. On the other hand, touching the screen with the finger works in the correct way.

With the `xinput -list` command, I get

```
corrado@corrado-Inspiron-17-7779:~$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0744:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

where I noticed that the `ELAN Touchscreen Pen` is missing in the Virtual Core Pointer.

Is it possible to make the Dell Active Stylus working on my notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same laptop model, and the short answer is no, the Active Stylus, or any stylus for that matter, will not work.

The reason is very simple. This model features a touchscreen, and not an active digitizer. A stylus requires an active digitizer to be able to read the various pressure levels and fine tips.

With a touchscreen, the stylus you are using is no better than using your finger.